# how to change/simplify joins in oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I have a join in a oracle query which looks like:

```
      FROM eiv.table1
           eiv.table2 b
       WHERE a.state_cd =
             b.state_code(+)
```

what does the `(+)` towards the end mean?

With this query I have noticed that sometimes I am getting an empty space when records do not match in tables.

Is this a left outer join or right?  How can this be simplified.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268732/converting-oracle-sql-select-into-posgresql-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    eiv.table1 a
LEFT JOIN
        eiv.table2 b
ON      b.state_code = a.state_cs
```

Before `9i`, `Oracle` did not support `ANSI` join syntax, and `(+)` clause was used instead.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it's a left outer join... Details always come from a, and only come from b when the condition is met...

FROM eiv.table1
           eiv.table2 b
       WHERE a.state_cd =
             b.state_code(+)

=

from evi.table1 a left join eiv.tableb b on (a.state_cd = b.state_code)

You might want to give some thought to using the same column name for the state code on both tables, but it may be a little late for that...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/outer_join.html

> "This might be what one want or it
>   might not. Assuming that we want to
>   return all numbers, even if the german
>   translation is missing, we need an
>   outer join. An outer join uses a (+)
>   on the side of the operator (which in
>   this case happens to be the equality
>   operator) where we want to have nulls
>   returned if no value matches:
>
> select    l.v "English",    r.v
>   "German" from    r,l where    l.i
>   =  r.i (+)   and   r.l(+)  =  'de';
>
> And this returns a row for each
>   english word, even if there is no
>   german translation:
>
> English              German
>   -------------------- -------------------- one two                  zwei three                drei four
>   five"